# How can I access the contents of a lock-out password-protected USB flash drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, password-protection, u3

I have a password protected Cruzer U3 flash drive. When trying to access the data contained on this drive, I typed the password incorrectly, and it is no longer prompting me for a password. I cannot access the drive's contents. Some Google searches* turned up [a page on Lockergnome](http://lockergnome.net/questions/81705/how-unlock-a-usb-u3-drive) that describes a situation similar to mine. However, none of the solutions I found appears to be viable. All of them suggest that I format my drive, which contains incredibly important documents. Is there an alternate way to retrieve my data without formatting the drive?

<sub>* Search terms included "Bypassing U3 password lock", "Unlocking locked USB flash drives", and "U3 Cruzer recovery"</sub>

Comment: If you have access to a Linux machine or live CD try plugging it into that. I've never tried it with the U3 password stuff, but I've gotten around other security measures just by simply using a Linux OS to view the files on removable media

Answer (score 0):

This device is designed to do this.  Many people have the same problem on the Sandisk forums and the answer is always the same.  Format the drive.

Sorry mate!

Comment: Just for typing the password incorrectly it does this?